# How can I set a value in memcache to expire at a specific time?

Tags: google-app-engine, python-memcached

I have a google app engine apps (created using python). I want to add a value to memcache but would like for the value to expire every midnight (PST) How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set an item's expiration time either as absolute epoch time, or as a relative time-to-expire of up to one month. See http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/functions.html

There's a second alternative. If you have a set of known keys that you'd like to expire at a given time each day, use a cron job.

Comment: I was having problems with the epoch time bit. I'll go with using a cron job to expire the keys. Thanks

Comment: @N.P There's really no need to waste your CPU time deleting them yourself - that's what the expiry time is _for_.